# How to save value in the plist and acces the plist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `UITableView` with a `UISwitch` button in it. I want that when I run  my application default value of the `UISwitch` button should be `ON`. If I toggle the switch button from on to off the value in the plist should change to `OFF`. If I quit the app and then I again run my app the value should again default to `ON` in the plist.

I have tried using `NSUserDefaults`, it works i.e when I change the value from `ON` to `OFF` the value in `NSUserDefaults` also changes. But when the app is run again the default value is not set to `ON`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    settings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Clock",@"Time Format",@"Weather",@"Degrees",nil];
    switchControl = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(205, 110, 20, 15) ];
    [self.switchControl addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:switchControl];
    NSString *viewdid = @"ON";
    userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userdefaults setObject:viewdid forKey:@"stateOfSwitch"];

}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSString    *_value= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"stateOfSwitch"];

    if([_value compare:@"ON"] == NSOrderedSame){
        [switchControl setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        [switchControl setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 4;
}
-(void)switchChanged:(id)sender
{

    app= (StopSnoozeAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

        NSString *value = @"ON";
    userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if(!switchControl.on){
            value = @"OFF";
            [userdefaults setObject:value forKey:@"stateOfSwitch"];
        }
        [userdefaults setObject:value forKey:@"stateOfSwitch"];
    [userdefaults synchronize];

}


//this is my second class where i am accessing my userdefaults key and depending on that hiding the views
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    NSString *_value= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"stateOfSwitch"];

    if([_value compare:@"ON"] == NSOrderedSame){
        newview.hidden = NO;
        newnewview.hidden =NO;
        firstview.hidden = NO;
        secondview.hidden = NO;
        thirdview.hidden = NO;



    }
    else if([_value compare:@"OFF"] == NSOrderedSame) {

        newview.hidden = YES;
        newnewview.hidden= YES;
        firstview.hidden = YES;
        secondview.hidden = YES;
        thirdview.hidden = YES;
    }

}
```

Comment: in application did finish loading u can set no to userdefaults

Comment: @Narayana how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In appDelegate did finish loading write below statements

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"OFF" forKey:@"stateOfSwitch"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you have not dump new values to plist?

Try to call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` after setting new value to `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: i have done this .my problem is when i change the value of the switch the value is getting changed but the problem is when i quit the application and run it once again the default value is not restored

Comment: Show us how do you store and restore that value.

Answer (score 0):

Either do

```
// set when launching the app
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"OFF" forKey:@"stateOfSwitch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

or

```
// set when terminating
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"OFF" forKey:@"stateOfSwitch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Furthermore, you should test your NSString using `isEqualToString:` as `compare:` may lead to false positives (e.g. if one of the strings is nil).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store a string, which has the potential for parsing bugs, when NSUserDefaults is perfectly capable of storing BOOLs directly.

Just store it like this:

```
#define StateOfSwitch @"StateOfSwitch"
-(void)switchChanged:(id)sender
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:switchControl.on forKey:StateOfSwitch];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

and then later, load the value like this:

```
switchControl.on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:StateOfSwitch];
```

(Note it's a good idea to never use string keys directly, it's better to #define them to prevent typo errors. Plus you get command + click to jump to definition, autocompletion, etc.)